# how can i parse the xml file in tcl script and read the some tag attribute and change the that attribute value

Tags: xml, tcl

i have below xml file suing tcl scripting language.

```
<workarea>
  <poller name="Poller1">
    <pollerAttribute loc="c:\abc" username="abc" password="xxx">
      <value>123</value>
    </pollerAttribute>
  </poller>
  <poller name="Poller2">
    <pollerAttribute loc="c:\def" username="def" password="xxx">
      <value>345</value>
    </pollerAttribute>
  </poller>
  .....
</workarea>
```

here i want to read the each tage with Poller name and then change the `password="xxx"` for that.
i am new to tcl scripting language.
any help will be great for me.
thanks in adavance.

Comment: You want a Tcl script to alter some attributes in an XML file?

Comment: yes. i want to modify the pollers password.

Answer (score 7):

By far the easiest way of doing this with Tcl is by using [tDOM](http://wiki.tcl.tk/8984) to manipulate the XML. You use an XPath expression to select the elements whose `password` attributes you want to alter, and then you can just iterate over those nodes and change them as necessary. Finally, you need to remember that changing the document in memory is *not* changing the document on disk; reading and writing the serialized document are important steps too.

```tcl
package require tdom

set filename "thefile.xml"
set xpath {//pollerAttribute[@password]}

# Read in
set f [open $filename]
set doc [dom parse [read $f]]
close $f
set root [$doc documentElement]

# Do the update of the in-memory doc
foreach pollerAttr [$root selectNodes $xpath] {
    $pollerAttr setAttribute password "theNewPassword"
}

# Write out (you might or might not want the -doctypeDeclaration option)
set f [open $filename "w"]
$doc asXML -channel $f -doctypeDeclaration true
close $f
```

That's about it. (You might need more care with how to select the elements with the right `password` attributes, and to supply the replacement passwords in a more sophisticated way, but those are finessing.)

Comment: after parsing the xml file to change password attribute value in my xml , i am not getting the first tag 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
can you please point out where i am doing wrong.
`foreach pollerName $pollerNames1 {
set size [file size $xmlPath]
set fd [open $xmlPath]
set xml [read $fd $size ]
set doc  [dom parse $xml]
close $fd

set rootNode [$doc documentElement]
foreach textNode [$rootNode childNodes] {
if { [$textNode nodeName] == "WorkerConfiguration" && [$textNode getAttribute "name"] == $polName } {

half part of code is in below comment...
`

Comment: ...continue
`
foreach subChildNode [$textNode childNodes] {
if { [string tolower [$subChildNode nodeName]] == [string tolower $finalPasscut] } {   
$subChildNode setAttribute  Password  "$passCut\_$todayDate"
}
}
}
set f [open $xmlPath w]
puts $f [$doc asXML -indent 4]
close $f
}
}
`

Comment: @picnic4u You're using base DOM methods to go over the document, which can easily go wrong when you don't quite have the document you expect. Use `selectNodes` as in my example _with the right XPath term_ and you'll get what you want. (Also, you don't need to look at the file size to read it; the efficiency bug that made that once recommended practice has been fixed for ages. Just `read $fd` will return everything and you'll not notice performance differences.)

Comment: `package require tdom` is creating problem `
Segmentation fault (core dumped)` in linux machine.i am using below version 
`tcl - tcl-8.0.5-35.i386`
`tdom - tdom-0.8.2-3.el5.i386`

can you please suggest me why it's creating problem.

Comment: do we have any alternative for tdom in tcl?